# Listening for specific data whilst using threading

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to listen on a port for specific message being transmitted to stop my program.

Here is the function that is listening using `sockets`:

```
def receive():
    host = ""
    port = 13000
    buf = 1024
    addr = (host,port)
    Sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    Sock.bind(addr)
    (data, addr) = Sock.recvfrom(buf)
    return data
```

I have made it run in the background with `threading`:

```
while True:
    r = threading.Thread(target=receive)
    r.start()
    if r == "stop":
        print "Stopped"
        break
    print "Running program"
```

When the `r = threading` is **inside the while loop**, *as above*, I get:

`error: [Errno 98] Address already in use`

And when I define `r = threading` **outside the while loop** (before it), I get:

`RuntimeError: threads can only be started once`

I have tried this, however when I send the "stop" command it sends the **thread RuntimeError** AND quits the program:

```
if r.is_alive == False:
    r.start()
```

Comment: Your while loop means that you are starting many threads that will all run `receive`. The first one will start but all the rest will fail with the error you are showing: `error: [Errno 98] Address already in use`. You need to start your receiver thread only once.

Comment: you are also going to need to close that socket in the spawned thread, unless Python does that when it goes out of scope.  Otherwise you are leaking them.  I think your flow needs more thinking about before you can decide what is the right answer to this question. You can only bind a socket once to the same address, which may explain one of your reported problems.

Comment: Also, not that I'm not sure you can do `if r == "stop":` - r doesn't equal a string, it's the thread, not the result/return value. You might want to look at using something like https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html to safely pass data between your child and parent threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using threading:

```
from socket import *
def receive():
    host = ""
    port = 13000
    buf = 1024
    addr = (host,port)
    Sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    Sock.bind(addr)
    while True:
        (data, addr) = Sock.recvfrom(buf)
        if data == "stop":
            print "Stopped"
            break
        print "Running program"

import threading
r = threading.Thread(target=receive)
r.start()
r.join()
```